# How to retrieve JSON keys without any buffer error?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Below is my JSON that I get from reading a text file using node js readFileSync.

```
{"MESSAGE":"Triggered for ID 453289","STATUS":"02","APPROVAL_COMPLETED":""}
```

Now when I try to get the keys of the JSON using the code below

```
Object.keys(json);
```

I ge the below error

```
The keys are 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30,31,32,33,34,35,36,37,38,39,40,41,42,43,44,45,46,47,48,49,50,51,52,53,54,55,56,57,58,59,60,61,62,63,64,65,66,67,68,69,70,71,72,73,74,75,76,77,78,79,80,81,82,83,84,85,86,87,88,89,90,91,92,93,94,95,96,97,98,99,100,101,102,103,104,105,106,107,108,109,110,111,112,113,114
```

Also if I try to get the value of the JSON element like below

```
json["STATUS"]; // I also used json.status (neither works)
```

I get the value as undefined.

Below is the entire code

```
var fs = $.require('fs');
var stream = fs.readFileSync('api.txt', 'utf8');
console.log("Global " +JSON.stringify(stream));
var data = JSON.parse(stream);
var retrievedData = JSON.stringify(data.retrievedData);
var json = JSON.parse(retrievedData);
console.log("The API Output is " +json);
var keys = Object.keys(json);
console.log("The keys are "+keys);
var flag = json["STATUS"];
//var retrievedData = stream.retrievedData;
console.log("flag is "+flag);
```

Below are the particulars

```
Output of Data is 

{"retrievedData":"{\"MESSAGE\":\"Triggered for Group ID 453289\",\"STATUS\":\"02\",\"APPROVAL_COMPLETED\":\"\"}","statusCode":200,"MESSAGE":"API successfully called"}

Output of retrievedData is

{"MESSAGE":"Triggered for ID 453289","STATUS":"02","APPROVAL_COMPLETED":""}
```

Please help in resolving the issues.

Comment: Looks like you just need to do JSON.parse ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that your data is a string, so you need to parse it into an object:

```js
let input = '{"MESSAGE":"Triggered for ID 453289","STATUS":"02","APPROVAL_COMPLETED":""}'

console.log(Object.keys(input));

let parsed = JSON.parse(input);

console.log(Object.keys(parsed));
console.log(parsed['STATUS']);
```

The error in your code is calling `var retrievedData = JSON.stringify(data.retrievedData);` - the data appears to already a string at that point, so you double encode it. You can just skip the `JSON.stringify` and it would work:

```js
var stream = `{
  "retrievedData": "{\\"MESSAGE\\":\\"Triggered for ID 453289\\",\\"STATUS\\":\\"02\\",\\"APPROVAL_COMPLETED\\":\\"\\"}"
}`

var data = JSON.parse(stream);

var retrievedData = data.retrievedData;

var json = JSON.parse(retrievedData);
console.log("The API Output is " +json);

var keys = Object.keys(json);
console.log("The keys are "+keys);

var flag = json["STATUS"];
```

Answer (score 1):

Dont stringify the JSON when passing it as a parameter to Object.keys().

```
var keys = Object.keys(json);
```

Instead of

```
var keys = Object.keys(JSON.stringify(json));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can directly apply a loop on retrievedData to find keys:-

```
for(var temp in retrievedData)
{
   console.log(temp)
}
```

Here temp will be your keys

Comment: Do one thing convert retrievedData into Object using JSON.parse and remove all conversion applied after that. then apply the same loop. it should work

Answer (score 0):

Try and change

```
var keys = Object.keys(JSON.stringify(json));
```

towards

```
var keys = Object.keys(json);
```

Does that help to resolve your issue?

Comment: ["0","1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","11","12","13","14","15","16","17","18","19","20","21","22","23","24","25","26","27","28","29","30","31","32","33","34","35","36","37","38","39","40","41","42","43","44","45","46","47","48","49","50","51","52","53","54","55","56","57","58","59","60","61","62","63","64","65","66","67","68","69","70","71","72","73","74","75","76","77","78","79","80","81","82","83","84","85","86","87","88","89","90","91","92","93","94","95","96","97","98","99","100"]

Comment: That indicates that you still do Object.keys() with a string - so with the output of stringify()